# For C++, what is the rule of feasibility of defining a function in another function?

Tags: c++, scope

I already know that a function object can be defined in another function's body. While I try to define a simple function in main function, error occurs.

```
int main(){
    void f(){}
    return 0;
}
```

Could a function be defined in another function?
Could a class and some of its member functions defined separately in another function or another **class body**? (bold words edit)
Is there a rule to follow?

edit:Thank you very much! But I misswrote class body as function, i.e the bold words, and now it is corrected. Could you tell more?

edit2:By the second question I should have writen:could a member function of a class defined in a function named F while the class declaration is also in the function F,and whatif F is a class defination? Just like these two:

```
//F is a function
int F(){
    class A{
        int f();
    };
    int A::f(){}
}

// F is a class
class F(){
    class A{
        int f();
    };
    int A::f(){}
}
```

Comment: You can define a lambda (an anonymous function object) and/or a local class with member functions inside a function. You can also *declare*, but not *define* a function inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could a function be defined in another function?

Not directly. There's no particular reason why not; the language simply doesn't allow it. You can *declare* a function inside another; but you can only *define* it in the surrounding namespace.

You can define named lambda variables, and local classes containing member functions.

```
int main() {
    auto l = []{std::cout << "lambda\n";};
    struct s {static void f() {std::cout << "member\n";}};

    l();
    s::f();
}
```

> Could a class and some of its member functions defined seperaterly in another function or another function?

Class members can only be defined inside the class or (for non-local classes) in a namespace. Unless the class is local, you can't define any member inside another function; if it is local, members can only be defined inside the class.

Comment: Sorry for my bad. In the second question, I mean could coding like this is legal:  int f(){ class A{ int f();}; int f(){} } ?

Comment: @heLomaN: Regarding your update, you can't define a class member in another class body either. The definition can only be in the class it's a member of, or a namespace.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I didn't express my question well. And I edited it. Could you help me again?

Comment: @heLomaN: No, you can't define a member of a local class directly directly within the function, only inside the class.

Comment: What about in another class, just as the code showed when F is a class?

Comment: Re "no particular reason", it probably had to do with access to the scope of the containing function. This was how Pascal nested routines worked. And at the machine code level it involves dynamically linked stack frames, I think they were called "Dijkstra displays" or something like that, with some complexity and inefficiency. C++11 lambdas solve that by not supporting conversion to raw function pointer when they capture: with a capture they're objects only, with `operator()` member function. Consider recursive lambda. In other words, we have come some way since early Pascal and C. ;-)

Comment: @heLomaN: No, only in the class itself or a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Any function shall be defined in a namespace region outside any other function but may be declared in any function block scope.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int ) { std::cout << "f( int )" << std::endl; }
void f( short ) { std::cout << "f( short )" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   void f( int );

   f( 1 );

   {
      void f( short );

      f( 2 );
   }
}
```

As for classes then a class can be defined inside a function. In this case it shall not have static member functions and all non-static member functions shall be defined inside the class. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   struct Multiply
   {
      constexpr unsigned int operator ()( unsigned int x, unsigned int y ) const
      {
         return ( y == 0 ? 0 : x + operator ()( x, --y ) );
      }
   };

   std::cout << Multiply()( 10, 10 ) << std::endl;
}
```

If a class is defined in some name space scope then its member functions can be defined separatly.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct Divide
{
    constexpr unsigned int operator ()( unsigned int x, unsigned int y ) const;
};

constexpr unsigned int Divide::operator ()( unsigned int x, unsigned int y ) const
{
    return ( x < y ? 0 : 1 + operator ()( x - y, y ) );
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << Divide()( 100, 10 ) << std::endl;
}
```

As for lambda expressions they are not functions. In fact they are anonymous local classes with defined operator function.

Answer (score 0):

> Could a function be defined in another function?

No.  You can *declare* a function anywhere, but you cannot *define* (that is, implement) a function inside another function (the exception being lambda functions).

> Could a class and some of its member functions defined separately in another function or another function?

I'm not sure what you are asking here because the sentence is not complete.  If you are asking if you can define a class inside a function:  yes, you can, but its usefulness would be limited since it would only be defined inside the function.

Comment: Note: although limited in functionality, such local classes work very well as predicates (when a lambda is not enough, such as when needing a templated/overloaded argument to `operator()`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agreed.  I was not stating they are useless, just that they are only useful within the function.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 introduced lambda expression to build a callable object in a function and capture variables. To define a member function in certain place, you'll probably define a lambda member in the class and assign a lambda to it.